# How can I save urls from dead Google Chrome window

Tags: google-chrome, browser, data-recovery, memory-leaks, process-explorer

I have Google Chrome incognito window open with more than 100 tabs. OS: Win10. When I was browsing one site, chrome window suddenly freezed and I can't anymore browse or see any tabs. So I left chrome in it's current state. I wan't to save urls from those chrome tabs.   Step-by-step instructions would be helpful.

1. Does Chrome incognito mode save currently opened tab urls in Chrome profile?
2. If I close freezed Chrome incognito window will all of tab-urls be lost?
3. How to recover urls from those 100 tabs?
4. If I create full memory dump of all Chrome processes using process explorer, how can I find tab urls from it?
5. Are there any other ways to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

*If* Chrome were still running, you could "Bookmark (all) open pages... Ctrl+Shift+D", even in an incognito window... but the whole point of *incognito mode* is to not leave any history of browsing, so once the window's closed the open tabs are forgotten.

---

Searching all it's memory is an idea... I'm not sure how or if you could differentiate between all the html links in all the webpages vs just the main page URLs.

I tried a test, having only one regular window open with three tabs, and one incognito window with one tab to a unique URL, and only about 200 entries of browsing history and less than a dozen bookmarks. Then:

1. Used the GNU debugger `gcore` to make a core dump of my Chromium processes (850MB)
   <sub>[I used Linux, but there should be plenty of equivalent windows tools too, for core dumps, strings & grep, like [How can I configure windows to generate a core dump from an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672572/how-can-i-configure-windows-to-generate-a-core-dump-from-an-application)]</sub>
2. Used `strings` to just find strings of 4+ printable characters (37MB)
3. `grep` for the unique URL (unique.com)

The resulting file, lines only containing the unique URL, was 26kb and had 343 lines, all from just one open tab.

- [There were also some *interesting* results like `http://google.ca/search?q=uniqueURL&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8` when I never searched google for the unique URL, and `https://staticxx.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?...&origin=uniqueURL`but I'm assuming those are from the unique URL's page itself, my Chromium isn't supposed to be googling every URL I type.]

Searching the strings from step 2 [for any URL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118034/how-can-i-extract-parse-a-complete-url-from-a-semi-random-string) with `egrep -o 'https?://[^ ]+' strings-file` found 18,292 results.

You might be able to find your 100 lost tabs somewhere in the tens of thousands (or more) of URL's from a memory / core dump, but it might be a lot easier to just search google from your own personal memory of what you were browsing.

Answer (score 0):

If you hover over the window you want to save and right click, you should get a context menu [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmeNd.png). If you do not, ensure the window you want to save is in focus and force a reload with F5, shft+F5, or ctrl+shft+F5 to make the context window show up the next time you try.

You can then click "bookmark all tabs" from the context menu, and it may appear to do nothing; but it usually still opens the bookmark all tabs interface, even when chrome is frozen or a completely black screen. If you type a string you will remember, and then hit enter, a folder with your open tabs should be saved somewhere in your bookmarks. To ensure that it worked, you can also try renaming the window in the same way, and it should change the text where it says "demonstration" in the image. When you next open chrome, look through your bookmarks to find a folder named the string you saved your tabs as, and you can right click the folder to reopen all tabs in a new window, or an new incognito window. If you used any tab groups, they will be subfolders which you can then also individually right click and choose open all in new tab group.

Comment: Welcome as a new contributor to [su]. According to [tour] and https://superuser.com/help/behavior, questions and answers should not include chitchat. I mention this b/c the first statement looks like a chitchat. If you think it's relevant, restructure your answer to put first a straightforward summary (TL;DR) that answers the question,  so that statement doesn't look so prominent. Ref. [answer]

Comment: yup, you're totally right, thanks; no reason to make extra fluff everyone has to read through to get an answer